# angular2/post request to django to create user

Tags: django, angular, httprequest

I am trying to create new users in my Angular app by sending post requests to Django backend (which is not developed by me but is believed to be implemented correctly).
In my sign up service, I have the following function to create new user

```
newUser(f: NgForm){
let username = f.controls['username'].value;
let password = f.controls['password'].value;
let email = f.controls['email'].value;

let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  headers.append('X-CSRFToken', this.getCookie('csrftoken'));

return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/users/', JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password, email: email}), {headers: headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

In my form component, I have onSubmit function that only "talks" to the sign up service

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
let res = this.signUpService.newUser(form).then(result => res = result, error => this.errorMessage = <any> error);
```

However, when I try to create new users, I get the following error:

> POST http://localhost:8000/users/ 401 (Unauthorized)

I am thinking that the backend might be configured in a way that only superuser can create new users, and, hence, that's what throwing an error.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you post the Django view, it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this issue also, there was nothing wrong with the Angular code, it was in the Django - the permissions were set to `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`and were changed to `AllowAny`